# Extract Form Data (PHP)

Tags: php, forms, validation

I'm working on a login/registration form for a school assignment, and I can't get the forms to retain any information when submitted. Whether the information is correct or incorrect, the form returns with blank values after being submitted. Here is the form code:

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors","on");
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
$labels = array("email" => "Email Address:",
                "password" => "Password:");
$submit = "Log In";
?>

<?php
echo "<form method='post'>";
foreach($labels as $field => $label)
{
    if($field != "password")
    {
        echo "<div><label for='$field'>$label</label>
        <input type='text' name='$field' id='$field' width='40%' maxlength='40' value='".@$$value."'></div>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<div><label for='$field'>$label</label>
        <input type='password' name='$field' id='$field' width='40%' maxlength='20' value='".@$$value."'</div>";
    }
}
echo "<div><input type='hidden' name='submitted' value='yes'>
<input type='submit' value='$submit' name='submit'></div>";
?>
```

The following is the validation code:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submitted']) and $_POST['submitted'] == 'yes')
{
    foreach($_POST as $field => $value)
    {
        if(empty($value))
        {
            $error_array[] = $field;
        }
        else
        {
            $good_data[$field] = strip_tags(trim($value));
        }
    }
    if(@sizeof($error_array) > 0)
    {
        $message = "<p class='error'>Login information is incorrect</p>";
        echo $message;
        extract($good_data);
        include('login.php');
        exit();
    }
    else
    {
        foreach($good_data as $field => $value)
        {
            $clean_data[$field] = mysqli_real_escape_string($cxn,$value);
        }
        $sql = "select * from customerdata where email='$clean_data[email]' and password='$clean_data[password]'";
        $result = mysqli_query($cxn,$sql) or die("<p class='error'>Couldn't connect to server.</p>");
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        if ($row > 0)
        {
            $sql2 = "update user_login set login_time=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP where email='$clean_data[email]'";
            $result2 = mysqli_query($cxn,$sql2) or die("<p class='error'>Couldn't connect to server.</p>");
            $_SESSION['auth'] = "yes";
            header("Location: catalog.php");
        }
        else
        {
            echo $message;
            extract($clean_data);
            include('login.php');
            exit();
        }
    }
}
else
{
    include("login.php");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you have `@$$value` in your input forms, you are firstly silencing the error in php saying that the $value isn't set in some of your include instances.

What would be advisable would be to save the username and password into their own distinct variables if received in the POST request and then echo these out into the value of the field, also by putting $$ you are trying to find a dynamically named variable, with the name of the value of $value, as opposed to the variable $value.

I think you want something like this -

```
foreach($labels as $field => $label)
{
    $value = '';
    if(!empty($_POST[$field ]) {
        $value = $_POST[$field];
    }

    if($field != "password")
    {
        echo "<div><label for='$field'>$label</label>
        <input type='text' name='$field' id='$field' width='40%' maxlength='40' value='".$value."'></div>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<div><label for='$field'>$label</label>
        <input type='password' name='$field' id='$field' width='40%' maxlength='20' value='".$value."'</div>";
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you. I'll add the same code to my registration form as well, and it should finally work for me.